# Setting camera preview buffer size

Tags: android, camera

I'm testing my app using HTC Wildfire with Android 2.2.1.
The default camera preview size is 768x432. I see it from device log:

```
12-19 18:41:34.088: D/QualcommCameraHardware(72): initPreview E: preview size=768x432
12-19 18:41:34.088: D/QualcommCameraHardware(72): initPreview E: preview size=768x432 videosize = 768 x 432
12-19 18:41:34.088: D/QualcommCameraHardware(72): mBufferSize=497664, mAlignedBufferSize=524288
```

OK, it works. But if I try to change preview size to some different value like 320x240 or 800x480 there is nothing but a mess of pixels on the screen. The most interesting thing here is that if I use preview with the buffer size smaller then the default one (497664) I get this error in the log:

```
12-19 18:52:49.288: E/Camera-JNI(5776): Manually set buffer was too small! Expected 497664 bytes, but got 144000!
```

So it is obvious that the actual buffer size is not changed. Is there any way to solve this?

I should also notice that there is no such problem on Asus Eee Pad Transformer with Android 3.2.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured out what was the problem.
It appears that on Android 2.2.1 you do have to set camera parameters BEFORE you call

```
camera.startPreview()
```

However on later systems like Android 3.2.1 this is no longer an issue (however it could be vendor specific).

Answer (score 0):

Camera on android is kind of voodoo.   I would recommend to look which preview sizes are actually supported (well, at least advertized) :

```
        Camera.Parameters cameraParameters = camera.getParameters();
        // print out parameters
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "flash modes:" + cameraParameters.getSupportedFlashModes());
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "autofocus:" + cameraParameters.getSupportedFocusModes());
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "preview formats:" + cameraParameters.getSupportedPreviewFormats());
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "scene modes:" + cameraParameters.getSupportedSceneModes());
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "white balance modes:" + cameraParameters.getSupportedWhiteBalance());
```

Unfortunately,  not all preview sizes are quaranted to work, even if they are in this list. 
At least not on motorola defy or htc hero.   So I do following:

```
            // as we know,  that big preview size can produce RE on HTC Hero,
        // we just iterate through allowed preview sizes until we find something proper
        //  go for maximal allowed preview size

        previewSize = cameraParameters.getPreviewSize();

        if (previewSize.width <= MIN_PREVIEW_WIDTH) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "preview size is too small:" + previewSize.width + "x" + previewSize.height);
            final List<Camera.Size> sizes = cameraParameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            Collections.sort(sizes, new Comparator<Camera.Size>() {
                public int compare(Camera.Size o1, Camera.Size o2) {
                    return new Integer(o2.width).compareTo(o1.width);
                }
            });

            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                cameraParameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
                camera.setParameters(cameraParameters);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "attempt preview size:" + size.width + "x" + size.height);
                try {
                    camera.startPreview();
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "...accepted - go along");
                    //  ok, camera accepted out settings.  since we know,
                    // that some implementations may choose different preview format,
                    // we retrieve parameters again. just to be sure
                    cameraParameters = camera.getParameters();
                    break;
                } catch (RuntimeException rx) {
                    // ups, camera did not like this size
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "...barfed, try next");
                }

            }
        } else {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, " accepted default preview size on the spot:" + previewSize.width + "x" + previewSize.height);
            camera.startPreview();
        }
```

Comment: I'm actually using cameraParameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()

Comment: I'm doing the same -  but I got exceptions while setting, and sometimes on preview callback if preview size was too big

Answer (score 0):

**My solution for 2.2 version:**

```
Camera.PictureCallback photoCallback=new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(data);
mCamera.startPreview();

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#addCallbackBuffer%28byte[]%29
        }
                };
```